# How do I create zones using location features?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, density

I have a list of rock art sites with a recording of every image within each site. For example, Site 1 has 4 kudu, 1 lion, 3 males and a locust; Site 2 has 2 leopards, 1 elephant and 3 giraffes; Site 3 etc etc. I have about 177 sites all with different attributes.

What I would like to do is create a map that generates a 'region' for each image type. So for example I want to circle all of the sites that have elephants painted in them and create an 'elephant zone'. I then want to do this for each attribute (image type) and see whether I can identify different painting traditions across the region.

I also want to measure where the greatest density of sites is.

Lastly, I want to calculate where the greatest diversity of image types exists. Some sites have only a few types where as others have more than 15 and I would like to know if these larger sites cluster somewhere or not.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to GIS.SE. Standard format is to ask one question per Question - it helps focus answers and be able to find relevant questions and answers in the future. It appears you have three distinct questions here: create a boundary [minimum bounding geometry] of like sites (simple), find density of sites (a little harder), and find density of diversity of sites (somewhat complex). There are also multiple ways to address each question. I would suggest splitting this up - you can reference them to each other if you like, and you may find that some of them already have answers here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible way to create such lasso region polygons is to use `Point Density` for each type of animal-or-whatever (can also be used to calculate the overall density).

It outputs a raster of relative density of the given points. If you choose an appropriate threshold density, you can threshold the raster using Map Algebra (`Con`) and convert the result to polygon by `Raster to Polygon` (then possibly enhance the looks of the result by converting to a convex hull and generalising).

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume your list of sites is a point feature, and that each image has it's own attribute (e.g., a field for elephant, another for kudu, another for leopard, etc.) with a count of how many of that image the site contains.

If that's the case, you could set up a loop to go through each field and buffer the point based on whether the field has a value. This gives you your zones, which you may want to dissolve for each image.

If you also have a total field that shows the count of fields with images for each site, you can symbolize the point based on that. More diverse sites would be larger, less diverse smaller.

I know I'm making assumptions about your data which may or may not not be valid. But this might give you some ideas, anyway.